# Camerax and Emulator on m1

Tags: android, android-emulator, apple-m1, android-camerax

I have a macbook m1 with the latest version of AndroidStudio. 
I have an app where I have implemented CameraX with ImageCapture. When I start the app on the device, the image acquisition takes place correctly. If, on the other hand, I install the app on the emulator (Android 11), when I click on the button to take the photo, nothing happens and the exception appears (I think it is code c) cpu permission denied. 
On the old macbook with chip intel I was able to take the picture.
Does anyone have the same problem as me?

Comment: Nothing????????

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?